# Liferay 7 Including third party library package (JsonPath) into portlet module

Tags: java, gradle, liferay, jsonpath, liferay-7

I'm trying to include JsonPath Library into my Liferay MVC Portlet.

I found thread on Liferay Help Center:

https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028710272-Resolving-Third-Party-Library-Package-Dependencies

but still I don't know what to do exactly.

I read that i should use **compileInclude** in `build.gradle` file, because it's include also dependences for library I want to.

That's how it's look like

```
#build.gradle

dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api"
    cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "3.0.2"
    compileInclude group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.4.0'
}
```

When I build a *.jar which i deploy to Liferay I have that error.

```
2021-07-15 06:56:16.994 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:272] Processing mycustomportlet2-1.0.0.jar
2021-07-15 06:56:26.140 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][DirectoryWatcher:1159] Unable to start bundle: file:/opt/liferay/osgi/modules/mycustomportlet2-1.0.0.jar
com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: mycustomportlet2 [1411]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.gson_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444) ~[org.eclipse.osgi.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428) ~[org.eclipse.osgi.jar:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1142) [bundleFile:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1175) [bundleFile:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1120) [bundleFile:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1032) [bundleFile:?]
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:272) [bundleFile:?]
```

I tried including also gson in build.gradle but then error shows another library that have unresolved requiremnt.

I'm using Liferay Portal 7.4-ga2 docker image with Java 11.

If you know how to do this without including a lot dependecies manually I will really appreciate a solution for that.

**EDIT**

I created `build.gradle` file with all includes needed to work. That's how it look:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "release.portal.api"
    cssBuilder group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.css.builder", version: "3.0.2"
    compileInclude group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.6.0'
    compileInclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.7'
    compileInclude  group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.12.3'
    compileInclude group: 'org.apache.tapestry', name: 'tapestry-json', version: '5.7.2'
    compileInclude group: 'org.apache.tapestry', name: 'commons', version: '5.7.2'
    compileInclude group: 'org.codehaus.jettison', name: 'jettison', version: '1.4.1'
    compileInclude group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20210307'
    compileInclude group: 'org.slf4j.impl', name: 'log4j12', version: '1.7.2'
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.averbis.com/m2/"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `compileInclude` external resources (which is possible, but should be your last resort), unfortunately you will need to include *all transitive dependencies* as well. You're including jayway/jsonpath, and gson is missing. So you'll need to `compileInclude` gson. And as you say, when you do that, a different library is missing - so you'll need to include it as well.

That's part of the reason why this should be your last resort.

An alternative is: Check if jayway/jsonpath or gson are OSGi bundles themselves - in which case you can just drop them into Liferay's `deploy` folder and they'll be dynamically resolved. Of course, in this case their transitive dependencies need to be resolvable as well, so you might need to deploy a couple more bundles than just these two. But this way, all modules that use these libraries will share the same bundle.

Either way, you can inspect a bundle's MANIFEST.mf for imports to figure out what they depend on. Note: there are mandatory and optional dependencies in there. You'll need to satisfy the mandatory ones and the optional ones that you're using. If the libraries in question aren't bundles, they're managing their dependencies differently. I'd at least suggest to the project teams to OSGi'ify their packages - but that's a fix for the long run.

There's a chapter on this on Liferay's University's (free, registration required) course [OSGi Basics](https://university.liferay.com/osgi-basics), called "Bringing along your dependencies" (disclaimer: by yours truly), where I still like the animated special effect visualizing the option to `compileInclude` and what it does to file size)

Comment: Thank you for the explaining, it helps me with understanding how it works. Unfortunately I didn't find OSGi bundle with JsonPath. But I manage to create working build.gradle file with compileIncludes I will add this to my question for interested people.